# Can't use Python on VScode after i installed R

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda

I am a complete noob when it comes to programming and happen to come across this error message:

```
: File C:\Users\Alaa\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. 
For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.comfwlink/?LinkID=135170
At line:1 char:3
+ . 'C:\Users\Alaa\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

PS Y:\Programming Files> conda activate base
```

I tried to create new paths for `conda`. i really don't know what to do please help

Comment: Does this link related to your problem? https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8428

Comment: On Windows workstations, PowerShell script execution is _disabled_ by default. Enable it with [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy).`-Scope` accepts one of 3 scopes; more specific ones have higher precedence: `LocalMachine` (requires admin rights), `CurrentUser`, or `Process` (current process only). The PowerShell CLI accepts a process-specific `-ExecutionPolicy <policy>` too. Execution policies can also be set via GPO, in which case they cannot be changed or overridden via `Set-ExecutionPolicy` or the CLI.